# How did this delete my Documents and Downloads?

Tags: bash, macos

I am running macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3. I wrote a script that I thought would help me clear clutter:

```
#! /bin/bash

clear

echo -e "\x1B[35m clearing system cache... \x1B[0m"
cd /System/Library/Caches
rm -rf ./*   

echo -e "\x1B[35m clearing library cache... \x1B[0m"
cd ~/Library/Caches
rm -rf ./*

echo -e "\x1B[35m clearing user cache... \x1B[0m"
cd ~/.cache
rm -rf ./*

echo -e "\x1B[35m removing outdated homebrew packages... \x1B[0m"
brew cleanup

echo -e "\x1B[35m clearing homebrew cache... \x1B[0m"
brew cleanup --cache

echo -e "\x1B[35m clearing temporary files... \x1B[0m"
cd ~
find . -type f -name '*~' -delete
find . -type f -name '*.*~' -delete
find . -type f -name '*.class' -delete
find . -type f -name '*.pyc' -delete
find . -type f -name '#*' -delete
find . -type f -name '.#*' -delete
rm .bash_history

echo -e "\x1B[35m clearing trash... \x1B[0m"
cd ~/Trash
rm -rf ./*

echo -e "\x1B[35m Done! \x1B[0m"
```

However, after I ran the script, my Documents and Downloads folders emptied. Which part of this does that?

Comment: It's possible that `cd` failed and didn't change the directory. Use `cd ... || exit 1` in the future.

Comment: Ok, so how about you put something in the documents, run this, and wait until it goes away. Done.

Comment: Don't `cd` then `rm`, use `rm` with the right prefix! If `cd` fails then you are making some kind of `rm -rf` from your private directory! See `Trash`? That's the wrong name...

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/Trash
rm -rf ./*
```

The trash is called `~/.Trash`, not `~/Trash`.  So the `cd` failed, and then you deleted everything from the current directory (which was your home directory).

You were crazy to run this without testing it first.  Use the command `trash` to move things to the trash rather than deleting them.  Don't wipe your trash.  Use `set -euo pipefail` at the top of your script so that it will stop if there are any errors.  Test using `rm -i` to ask for confirmation before deleting a file.